# Can't update a foreign key on an attached graph

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have an attached graph object and I can't figure out how to change the foreign key on a record. I have a Load record saved in my db. I retrieve said record by id with tracking on. I

```
public partial class Load 
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual int AccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

I then retrieve the customer record that I want to associate with the Load record

```
public partial class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

No matter what I do, I get some sort of exception is thrown.

```
        var customer = context.Customers.Where(x => x.Id == customerId).SingleOrDefault();
        load.Customer = customer;
        load.CustomerId = customer.Id;
        load.ModifiedByApplicationUserId = userId;
        load.ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        context.Entry(load).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
```

What is the proper way to go about changing the foreign key relationship on an attached graph object?

Edit. I have added the exception.

> [InvalidOperationException: Attaching an entity of type 'Triton.Core.Models.Identity.ApplicationUser' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.]
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachSingleObject(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntitySet entitySet) +690
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddEntityToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean doAttach) +130
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.AddEntityToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean doAttach) +65
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach) +67
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach) +340
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach) +209
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(Boolean doAttach) +164
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity) +510
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Attach>b__9() +97
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName) +354
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity) +200
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.set_State(EntityState value) +357
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1.set_State(EntityState value) +42
>      Triton.Service.LoadService.UpdateCustomer(Load load, Int32 customerId, Int32 userId) in d:\BitBucket\trunk\Triton\Triton.Service\LoadService.cs:73
>      Triton.Web.Controllers.LoadsController.Customer(LoadViewModel model) in d:\BitBucket\trunk\Triton\Triton.Web\Controllers\LoadsController.cs:138
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +180
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +434
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
>      Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.EndInvokeActionMethod_callback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      Castle.Proxies.Invocations.AsyncControllerActionInvoker_EndInvokeActionMethod.InvokeMethodOnTarget() +103
>      Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +117
>      Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.CastleInvocationToAlternateMethodContextAdapter.Proceed() +48
>      Glimpse.Mvc.AlternateType.EndInvokeActionMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context) +152
>      Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateTypeToCastleInterceptorAdapter.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) +183
>      Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +483
>      Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +203
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d() +117
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() +323
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() +323
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +72
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651688
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Why all properties on your model are virtuals?

Comment: You really need to run the app and get the exact error message and post it, even if you think it's to generic. Also post the entire controller and view that handles the update. We need a bit more information in order to help you out.

Comment: @danihp I didn't create the model. Just haven't removed the virtual keyword.

Comment: Looking at your error, which one of your entities inherits from `Triton.Core.Models.Identity.ApplicationUser`? It seems like the error might even stem from something outside what you've shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had an object in a sub class that was being referenced so EF was trying to add it to the graph. Once I nullified that object, everything worked properly.